# Can not save credentials in Keychain after resign app

Tags: ios, keychain

I wrote an App which saves the user credentials in the iOS Keychain using the KeychainItemWrapper class.
All works fine, but if the App is getting resigned for enterprise use, saving credentials do not work anymore.

I get the following Error but the App is not crashing:

```
SecItemCopyMatching: missing entitlement
securityd[2314] <Error>: Directory[2312] SecItemCopyMatching: missing entitlement
securityd[2314] <Error>: Directory[2312] SecItemAdd: missing entitlement
securityd[2314] <Error>: Directory[2312] SecItemCopyMatching: missing entitlement
securityd[2314] <Error>: XYZ[2312] SecItemAdd: missing entitlement
```

I initiate the class a follows:

```
KeychainItemWrapper *wrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"MYAPP_credentials" accessGroup:nil];
[keychain setObject:userName forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
[keychain setObject:password forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
```

I tried also to create an Entitlements.plist (using XCode 4.5.2)

[image]

and the following code:

```
KeychainItemWrapper *wrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"p7s1_dictionary" accessGroup:@"net.XYZ.directory"];
[keychain setObject:userName forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
[keychain setObject:password forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
```

While doing this I get an App crash with the following message:

```
Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain],  /Users/omid/Documents/Workspace/Xcode workspace/Directory/KeychainItemWrapper.m:305
2012-11-11 19:51:48.860 Directory[4162:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception  'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'
First throw call stack:
(0x32c7c2a3 0x33b3a97f 0x32c7c15d 0x348252af 0x32cbf 0x3230f 0x43aad 0x3488aef5 0x347ca9f1  0x347ca90d 0x39d9d5df 0x39d9cccb 0x39dc5133 0x32bc274d 0x39dc5593 0x39d2915d 0x32c51683  0x32c50ee9 0x32c4fcb7 0x32bc2ebd 0x32bc2d49 0x3a9c02eb 0x3a47e2f9 0x1ac69 0x1a140)
```

Update:
That's the script I use to resign

```
IPA="path to the .ipa file"
PROVISION="path to the .mobileprovision file"
CERTIFICATE="iPhone Distribution: a name"
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
unzip -q "$IPA"
rm -rf Payload/*.app/_CodeSignature Payload/*.app/CodeResources
cp "$PROVISION" Payload/*.app/embedded.mobileprovision
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "$CERTIFICATE" --resource-rules Payload/*.app/ResourceRules.plist Payload/*.app
zip -qr resigned.ipa Payload
rm -rf Payload
```

I would be thankful for any hint.

Comment: looks like you're not correctly code-signing the app

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're not correctly code-signing the app. the code has no influence on the entitlements.

make sure the bundle identifier is correct and the codesigning works